# How to change position in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

The change of position in the modes is still a bit of a mystery to me.

I just wanted to align two character models, but when I switch to edit mode, one of them changes its position. This time, I tried to align some facial features to that of the other character, but when I go to object mode, everything looks like a mess.

There is another related issue. Is there a way to change the pose position in the edit mode? The idea is that I can try out different poses for UV mapping. I have a hard time understanding why the textures are so distorted when in pose mode, as I cannot check the position of the vertices and their relation to the UV map.

Comment: Is your model posed somehow? If so, then in object mode, you see the pose. In edit mode, you are editing the plain model, without any pose deformations.

Comment: Yes, I assume it is posed by character creator. This is the basis I am working with. Is there no way to non-destructively pose the character in edit mode?

Comment: I am not actually sure, what the problem is. If you are trying to make the poses the same you do that in pose mode, not edit mode.

Comment: I want to make the pose the same to be able to transfer facial features of one character to the other. For this the models and their poses must be aligned.

Comment: I am still not sure what do you mean by "transfering facial features", but to change the pose, select your armature, go to pose mode and edit the pose there.

Comment: Either through shrink-wrapping or by snapping vertices of one character to the surface of the other character.

Comment: that would change the model itself, not the pose. If that is waht you want, reset the pose and then do that in edit mode (you probably dont even need to reset the pose). But if you make some big changes to the model, it may ruin the weight painting. I can't help you much more than this without seeing the model and some more detailed description of what you want to do. You should probably edit your quesetion to be more specific and idealy add some screenshots.